# Generate identically distributed dependent normal random numbers with prespecified sum

Tags: normal-distribution, random-generation, sum

How do I generate $n$ identically distributed but not independent normal random numbers such that their sum falls within a prespecified interval $[a,b]$ with probability $p$?

(This question is motivated by generating a random walk that ends up at a prespecified point: [Random process not so random after all (deterministic)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/358870/1352). Since a continuous random variable has zero probability of reaching an exact number, we do the second best thing and ask for an entire interval to end up in.)

---

EDIT: [Generating samples from singular Gaussian distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/159313/1352) has been proposed as a duplicate, which in turn is closed as a duplicate of [Generate normally distributed random numbers with non positive-definite covariance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/63817/1352). I agree that both of these are helpful. However, the point of the current question (more specifically, of the answer) is to first figure out that we can use a multivariate normal distribution to address the question, and second, what kind of covariance matrix works. How to sample from a distribution with that covariance is a third step, where the linked threads are helpful.

Comment: also see the literature on [Brownian bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) ?

Comment: @BenBolker: that sounds like a much better idea than mine. Would you be interested in writing up an answer?

Comment: maybe I'll get to it, but anyone else who is reading this should feel free to jump in and write up an answer.  I don't mind.

Comment: FWIW Brownian bridges are a more specific case - the sum is deterministically, exactly equal to a specified value $T_1$, not "within a given range with a given probability" ... arguably a better answer to the original question, but not to your generalization ...

Comment: @BenBolker: would it make sense to nominate the original question for reopening so you can post your BB there?

Comment: Sure.  Again, I may or may not be able to get to answering quickly ...

Comment: (Sorry, of course I mean "BB-BB".)

Comment: @BenBolker: I have nominated the original question for reopening, and also flagged it for the mods, in case my explanatory comment disappears in the sea of comments. Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: @BenBolker, I've reopened the thread. Please provide your answer at your convenience.

Comment: done. .........

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating samples from singular Gaussian distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159313/generating-samples-from-singular-gaussian-distribution)

Comment: Change the basis to one that includes the sum.  The resulting distribution is still multivariate Normal. [Sample the sum  from the truncated (univariate) Normal distribution.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238602/sampling-from-truncated-normal)  Invert the change of basis.

Answer (score 7):

We will generate multivariate normals $X\sim MN(\mu, \Sigma)$ with $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that their sum satisfies our condition. Let $Z=X_1 + \dots + X_n$.

As a common mean, we choose

$$ \mu_1 = \dots = \mu_n = \frac{a+b}{2n}. $$

In order that $Z\in[a,b]$ with probability $p$, its standard deviation should fulfill

$$ \sigma_Z = \frac{b-a}{q_\alpha}, $$

where $q_\alpha$ is the standard normal quantile to the level $\alpha$, here $\alpha=1-\frac{1-p}{2}$.

We now need to specify $\Sigma$. We have a lot of leeway here. Let us assume that we want each $X_i$'s variance to be $\sigma^2$ and the covariance be $\text{cov}(X_i,X_j)=\tau$ for $i\neq j$. The key to creating a "good" $\Sigma$ is [this previous answer by probabilityislogic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19953/1352). It yields that the sum of our $X_i$s has variance

$$ n\sigma^2 + n(n-1)\tau $$

so we need that

$$ n\sigma^2 + n(n-1)\tau = \frac{b-a}{q_\alpha}.$$

We also need to ensure that $\Sigma$ is positive definite, but this is not overly hard. The easiest way to do this is to ensure that all entries in $\Sigma$ are positive, e.g., by setting

$$ \sigma^2 := \frac{\sigma_Z^2}{2n}, \quad \tau := \frac{\sigma_Z^2}{2n(n-1)}, $$

but this gives very small values and very boring cumulative sums and trajectories:

[image: boring]

Less boring is to set

$$ \sigma^2 := 1, \quad \tau := \frac{1}{n-1}\big(\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{n}-\sigma^2\big), $$

which yields much more interesting trajectories:

[image: interesting]

Note that setting this does indeed yield a valid covariance matrix, because $\Sigma$ is then of the form $\Sigma_{ij} = m(i-j)$, namely

$$ m(0) = \sigma^2, \quad m(j) = \tau\text{ for }j>0, $$

and we have that

$$ \sum_{j>0} |m(j)| = (n-1)|\tau| = \big|\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{n}-\sigma^2\big| = \big|\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{n}-1\big| < 1 = \sigma^2 = m(0), $$

which is a sufficient condition for $\Sigma$ to be strictly positive definite by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) (Point 7 under ["Further Properties"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties)).

R code below, but first, please go and upvote [probabilityislogic's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19953/1352).

```
n_steps <- 1000
target_min <- 1.99
target_max <- 2.01
target_prob <- 0.99

target_mean <- mean(c(target_min,target_max))
target_sd <- (target_max-target_mean)/qnorm(p=1-(1-target_prob)/2)

mm <- rep(target_mean/n_steps,n_steps)

# boring setting:
# sigma_sq <- target_sd^2/(2*n_steps)
# tau <- target_sd^2/(2*n_steps*(n_steps-1))

sigma_sq <- 1
tau <- (target_sd^2/n_steps-sigma_sq)/(n_steps-1)

CC <- matrix(tau,nrow=n_steps,ncol=n_steps)
diag(CC) <- sigma_sq

library(MASS)
foo <- mvrnorm(1,mu=mm,Sigma=CC)
sum(foo)

plot(cumsum(foo),type="l",xlab="",ylab="")
abline(h=target_mean,lty=2)
```