# How do I generate a conditioned Brownian motion?

Tags: simulation, brownian-motion

Suppose I want to generate a random Brownian motion $B$ on $[0,1]$ such that:

1. $B_0=x_0$
2. $B_1=x_1$
3. $\max B_t = M$
4. $\min B_t = m$

The first two conditions a not difficult to impose. However I have trouble incorporating the 3th and 4th conditions, especially the fact that $M$ and $m$ have to actually be attained (rather then $M,m$ only being bounds).

Of course I want to do this in such a way that the probability of generating a specific walk is the correct conditional probability (as induced by the standard pdf on the set of Brownian motions).

Comment: Check W. Huber's https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/305058/7224

Comment: @Xi'an great, thanks!